# "Property Set method not found" error when trying to set DenyAddAndCustomizePages

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, configuration

I'm trying to set `DenyAddAndCustomizePages` property to 0. I execute the following in SharePoint Online Management Shell:

```
Set-SPOsite https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/ -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
```

But I receive the following error:

> Set-SPOsite : Property set method not found. At line:1 char:1
>   + Set-SPOsite https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/ -DenyAddAndCustomizePag ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-SPOSite], ServerException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException,Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.SetSite

NOTE: mycompany is a placeholder for the real company name.

If I execute the following:

```
 Get-SPOsite https://mycompany.sharepoint.com  | Format-List
```

I get the output:

```
LastContentModifiedDate           : 17/12/2015 07:33:40
Status                            : Active
ResourceUsageCurrent              : 0
ResourceUsageAverage              : 0
StorageUsageCurrent               : 0
LockIssue                         :
WebsCount                         : 0
CompatibilityLevel                : 0
DisableSharingForNonOwnersStatus  :
Url                               : https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/
LocaleId                          : 3082
LockState                         : UnLock
Owner                             :
StorageQuota                      : 1048576
StorageQuotaWarningLevel          : 0
ResourceQuota                     : 300
ResourceQuotaWarningLevel         : 255
Template                          : EHS#1
Title                             :
AllowSelfServiceUpgrade           : False
DenyAddAndCustomizePages          : Unknown
PWAEnabled                        : Unknown
SharingCapability                 : ExternalUserAndGuestSharing
SandboxedCodeActivationCapability : Unknown
DisableCompanyWideSharingLinks    : Unknown
StorageQuotaType                  :
```

What can I do to disable `DenyAddAndCustomizePages` property?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from O365 Admin center

[image]

Sorry for bad screen

Comment: but then you have to wait about 24 hours

Comment: Thanks for the response, I know it, but I didn't want to wait for 24 hours. Why there is no property set method. I recall I could do it in the past.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried running:

```
Set-SPOsite https://mycompany.sharepoint.com -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
```